# Jenkins Artifactory plugin not detecting my compiler during maven build

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am currently trying to get a pipeline going using the artifactory Jenkins plugin. When I use the plugin as a buildstep in a jenkins freestyle project, it works perfectly. When I run maven directly from within the pipeline, it works perfectly. When I run maven through the Artifactory plugin using the script below, it fails. The error I get is:

> No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running
>   on a JRE rather than a JDK?

This is my current script:

```
node {

    stage ('clone') {
        git credentialsId: 'git', url: '<URL to GIT repo>'
    }

    stage ('build and deploy') {
        env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'JDK8'}"
        env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"

        def server = Artifactory.server "arti-test"
        def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
        buildInfo.env.capture = true
        def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
        rtMaven.tool = 'M3'
        rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot'
        rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'

        rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo

        buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, maxDays: 7, deleteBuildArtifacts: true
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The next release of the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin will include an API for setting the JDK to be used for Maven and Gradle Pipeline builds. See this issue that tracks this task:
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-848
As a temporary workaround, you can add your JDK/bin directory to the PATH environment variable on the Jenkins build agent. You need to add it directly on the agent machine (not through Jenkine).